# How do I print a 2D array filled with 1s and 0s?

Tags: java

I'm trying to print a 2D array (size specified by user) with 1s and 0s. However, every time I try to run I get random numbers and letters like "[[I@4eec7777" instead of the 2D array. I commented out the for loops and think I have narrowed down the problem to the initialization of the array? I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
    System.out.print("How many rows? : ");
    int numRows = userInput.nextInt(); //numRows works
    System.out.print("How many columns? : ");
    int numCols = userInput.nextInt(); //numCols works
    int randomArray[][] = new int[numRows][numCols]; 
//    for (int row = 0; row < randomArray.length; row++) {
//      int temp = (int) ((Math.random()*2)+1);
//      for (int col = 0; col < randomArray[row].length; col++) {
//        if (temp % 2 == 0) randomArray[row][col] = 1;
//      }
//    }
    System.out.println(randomArray);
```

Comment: to print Arrays you should use Arrays.toString() you have to import Arrays.
For nested Array deepToString Method

Comment: You can't just print arrays like that, you will need loops to index over the contents of an array.

Comment: It is commented out underneath, it will loop through each row and column and assign a value (0 or 1). I am pretty sure this works?

Comment: Hi! Just if curious: the value shown after @ is the hexadecimal representation of the array's hash code. That's because arrays don't override Object.toString(), so the default method is called, which will show: `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what most of that means, just started coding java last year ;)

Comment: You'll get it soon. Welcome to java coding, it will be great, trust me : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

Arrays don't override the toString() method in Java.
If you try printing one directly you will get the className + @ + the hex of the hashCode of the array, as defined by Object.toString();

### Solution

Since Java 5 you can use Arrays.toString(arr) or Arrays.deepToString(arr) for arrays within arrays. Note that the Object[] version calls .toString() on each object in the array

So you can easily print your nested array by

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(randomArray));
```

Here the full code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Whatever {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("How many rows? : ");
        int numRows = userInput.nextInt(); //numRows works
        System.out.print("How many columns? : ");
        int numCols = userInput.nextInt(); //numCols works
        int randomArray[][] = new int[numRows][numCols]; 
        for (int row = 0; row < randomArray.length; row++) {
          int temp = (int) ((Math.random()*2)+1);
          for (int col = 0; col < randomArray[row].length; col++) {
            if (temp % 2 == 0) randomArray[row][col] = 1;
          }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(randomArray));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that, it gives an error: cannot find symbol on "Array".

Comment: Arrays and you have to import it, your IDE will probably give you a hint

Comment: @DavidDerber You need to import the `Arrays` class.  Just stick `import java.util.Arrays;` at the top of your file, beneath the package statement.

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it.

Comment: @DavidDerber don't forget to mark the answer as correct, as it will help others as well

Comment: You're welcome @DavidDerber :)

Comment: Yep, it makes me wait a bit longer before marking as correct.

Comment: @Alex, if you could edit the answer to include why this works and why the OP's code did not, this answer would probably attract more upvotes :)

Comment: @DavidDerber my bad then! : )

Comment: no worries, thanks for the help!

Comment: I gave a bit context

Comment: it looks nice now. crystal clear

Comment: @aran  Thanks :)